# Basic calculation in python

Tags: python

I wrote a simple function to find mean, variance and co-variance of a randomly generated dataset. 
But when I compared the output with the output from Numpy functions, I get a slight difference in result.

Can someone please advise why is it so?

```
import random
import numpy as np

def basic_calc():

    x = np.random.randn(10)
    y = np.random.randn(10)

    print(x, y)
    print("########\n########\n Using Basic Calc: ")
    mean_x = np.sum(x)
    mean_x /= x.size
    print("Mean of X: ", mean_x)
    var = 0
    for i in range (9):
        var +=  (x[i] - mean_x)**2
    variance_x = var/(x.size-1)
    print("Variance of X: ", variance_x)
    covar = 0
    for i in range (9):
        covar +=  (x[i] - mean_x)*(y[i] - np.mean(y))
    covar_xy = covar/(y.size-1)
    print("Co-Variance of XY: ", covar_xy)
    print("########\n########\n Using Numpy Functions: ")
    print("Mean of X: ",np.mean(x))
    print("Variance of X: ", np.var(x))
    print("Co-Variance of X,Y: ", np.cov(x,y
```

Edited:

Output:

Using Basic Calc:

```
Mean of X:  -0.37229498827575525
Variance of X:  0.9799024073066904
Co-Variance of XY:  -0.05818610994017605
```

Using Numpy Functions:

```
Mean of X:  -0.37229498827575525
Variance of X:  0.8916536385612055
Co-Variance of X,Y:  [[ 0.99072627 -0.09117693]
 [-0.09117693  0.67371543]]
```

Variance and Co variance are not exactly same for both methods used.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: You haven't even shown what the difference was between this and numpy output. How can anyone help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in `range` definition. Change your code from:

```
for i in range(9)
```

to:

```
for i in range(10)
```

The results will then align. Remember that `range(x)` counts from 0 to x-1 inclusive, and Python / Numpy indexing begins at 0.

Comment: one more question, np.cov(x,y) returns an array where [0][0] is basically variance of x, but the values dont match for me:
np.var(x) = 1.0763793197998102 and np.cov(x,y) = [[ 0.79680529 -0.16501283]
 [-0.16501283  0.40492357]]. 
any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Read up on `np.cov` in the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html). You need to extract one item, e.g. `x[0][0]` from the array to match your result.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check whether `range(9)` is really what you want to do as it will index from 0 to 8, while `range(10)` will index from 0 to 9.

Now comes the definition of variance, you have the variance n that you use when you have a full set, and the variance n-1 that you use when you have a sample.

The difference between the 2 is whether the value m = sum(xi) / n is the real average or whether it is just an approximation of what the average should be.

Variance n gives the real variance and is used for cases like variance of a height of class (data set is full). In this case we use,

```
sum([(xi - m) ** 2 for xi in dataset]) / len(dataset)
```

Variance n-1 is just an approximation, and used in cases like price of a stock, the value gets better as more data set is added. In this case we use,

```
sum([(xi - m) ** 2 for xi in dataset]) / (len(dataset) - 1)
```

To get the same result, In numby you can use `ddof` parameter, by default it is `ddof=0`. So for variance n-1 you will simply do `ddof=1`:

```
np.var(dataset, ddof=1)
```

and,

```
sum([(xi - m) ** 2 for xi in dataset]) / (len(dataset) - 1)
```

Comment: logical error. now i understand how .var works. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: variance n and variance n-1, a lot of people ignore it and get error. Edited my answer for error in range too.